# Bad results while getting file details C

Tags: c, file, file-permissions

I have the following function that abstract the handling of stat struct in C

```
int isdir(const char *filename) {
    struct stat st_buf;
    stat(filename, &st_buf);
    if(S_ISDIR(st_buf.st_mode))
       return 0;
    return 1;
}
```

And the main function calling `isdir`

```
int main(...) {
    struct dirent *file;
    DIR *dir = opendir(argv[1]);

    while(file = readdir(dir)) {
        printf("%d\n", isdir(file->d_name));
    }
    closedir(dir);
    /* other code */
}
```

I have a folder called Test as a parameter of the program and within two files, one is a regular file called "archivo" and a folder called "carpeta". My program prints 1 and 1,  from the file and the the folder, when it should be 0 and 1. I can't see where is the error.

The stat function ran in terminal gives the output for the file and the folder.

```
Fichero: «archivo»
Tamaño: 0           Bloques: 0          Bloque E/S: 4096   fichero regular
Dispositivo: 805h/2053d Nodo-i: 3159580     Enlaces: 1
Acceso: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1000/alejandro)   Gid: ( 1000/alejandro)
Acceso: 2013-10-31 21:08:57.556446728 -0300
Modificación: 2013-10-31 21:08:57.556446728 -0300
  Cambio: 2013-10-31 21:08:57.556446728 -0300
Creación: -

Fichero: «carpeta/»
Tamaño: 4096        Bloques: 8          Bloque E/S: 4096   directorio
Dispositivo: 805h/2053d Nodo-i: 3147783     Enlaces: 2
Acceso: (0775/drwxrwxr-x)  Uid: ( 1000/alejandro)   Gid: ( 1000/alejandro)
Acceso: 2013-10-31 21:19:11.728526599 -0300
Modificación: 2013-10-31 21:19:20.867833586 -0300
Cambio: 2013-10-31 21:19:20.867833586 -0300
Creación: -
```

Comment: Did you check the return value of stat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `file->d_name` is just a filename, it doesn't include the directory path. So `isdir()` is looking for the file in the current directory, not the directory named in `argv[1]`. You need to pass the directory to `isdir()`, and then concatenate the directory and file names with a `/` delimiter between them before calling `stat()`.

```
int isdir(const char *dirname, const char *filename) {
    struct stat st_buf;
    char *fullname = malloc(strlen(dirname)+strlen(filename)+2); // +2 for the slash and trailing null
    strcpy(fullname, dirname);
    strcat(fullname, "/");
    strcat(fullname, filename);
    if (stat(fullname, &st_buf) == -1) {
        perror(fullname);
        free(fullname);
        return 0;
    }
    free(fullname);
    return !S_ISDIR(st_buf.st_mode);
}
```

Then you should call it:

```
isdir(argv[1], file->d_name));
```

Comment: Excellent answer, I was programming with my mind on one folder, but the code wasn't working there haha. As you edited the answer, I remade the function very close like you, with strcpy and strcat.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely `stat` is failing.  Try checking:

```
 if( -1 == stat(filename, &st_buf)) {
   perror( filename );
   return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another problem is that you're calling readdir twice, once in your while () construct, and once afterwards.  It is reporting data for the hidden directories .  and ...

Comment: God, translation problems, I tried to translate the code, didn't work, I will solve that, but thanks and, in this case you're right too.